# Getting "null" value in array from values before the previous input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array so store 1 for correct answer from a quiz and 0 for wrong answer in the quiz. I am able to attain the "1" or "0" value in the array in the next question. However questions before that gives me null value.

For example when I complete question 1 and attempt question 2 
my array=[1].
When I complete question 2 and attempt question 3
my array = [NULL,1].
Instead, I should receive [1,1]. Assuming all both answers are right. This goes on till my last question [null,null,null,null,1].
Please kindly check my code and tell me my mistake. What I am doing is checking the answer if it is right if it is I will insert 1 into the array if not I will insert a 0. There are total 5 questions to this quiz. "questionIndex" is the question number

```
 Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
var array = [];
i = this.questionIndex;
if(this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
    array[i] = 1;   
    this.score++;
}
else{
    array[i] = 0;
}
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(array);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =myJSON;
this.questionIndex++;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an array object `var array = []` with local scope, you can create an `array` property for your `Quiz` object and then append values to it. This will prevent the `array` variable from being overwritten every time the function is run. Try the code below.

```
Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
  if (!this.array) this.array = [];
  i = this.questionIndex;
  if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
    this.array[i] = 1;
    this.score++;
  } else {
    this.array[i] = 0;
  }
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(this.array);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;
  this.questionIndex++;

}
```

I have replaced

```
var array = [];
```

with

```
if (!this.array) this.array = [];
```

This will create the `this.array` property if it doesn't exist and initialize to an empty array. Then I have replaced all subsequent use of `array` to `this.array`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is

```
var array = [];
```

since you are clearing up the array before every `guess`.

**Either you can place this line out of the array**, or Replace this line with

```
var existingGuess = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; //take the guess from the previously shown JSON
var array = [];
try
{
   array = JSON.parse( existingGuess );  
}
catch(){}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it does not work. The entire script won't work.

Comment: @alexvin Please share a working snippet demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I tried placing the var array = []; out of the function and it works. Thank you for pointing out the mistake

Comment: @alexvin Glad it worked for you. However, I would recommend against polluting the global scope and have the array as part of the `Quiz` object itself.